# Batch to Bash Script

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, batch

Could I get some help converting this batch script to an shell script? I don't know how to get the second part working, would I just pipe the first into the 2nd instead of having the brackets? (and changing the `%%a` stuff):

```
echo off
for %%a in ("*.aac") do (
  ffmpeg -i "%%a" -an -vcodec copy "%%~na.jpg"
  "ffmpeg.exe" -loop 1 -i  "%%~na.jpg" -i "%%a" -c:v libx264 -preset veryslow -tune stillimage -crf 18 -pix_fmt yuv420p -c:a aac -shortest -b:a 192k -shortest "%%~na.mp4" )
pause;
```

Comment: You should add details about what the script is supposed to do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure what is the purpose of the script but this solution should work:

```bsh
for file in *.aac; do
    ffmpeg -i "$file" -an -vcodec copy "${file%aac}jpg"
    ffmpeg -loop 1 -i  "${file%aac}jpg" -i "$file" -c:v libx264 -preset veryslow -tune stillimage -crf 18 -pix_fmt yuv420p -c:a aac -shortest -b:a 192k -shortest "${file%aac}mp4"
done
```

I replaced:

- `%%a` by the `$file` shell variable;
- `%%~na` which is removing the file extension by `${file%aac}`;
- `ffmpeg.exe` by the `ffmpeg` command.

Comment: Whoops! Thanks for correcting my mistake and good point with the portable parameter expansion.

Comment: No problem - upvoted :)